# Why to use Interfaces, Multiple Inheritance vs Interfaces, Benefits of Interfaces?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I still have some confusion about this thing. What I have found till now is

(Similar questions have already been asked here but I was having some other points.)

> 1. Interface is collection of ONLY abstract methods and final fields.
> 2. There is no multiple inheritance in Java.
> 3. Interfaces can be used to achieve multiple inheritance in Java.
> 4. One Strong point of Inheritance is that We can use the code of base class in derived class without writing it again. May be this is the most important thing for inheritance to be there.

Now..

> Q1. As interfaces are having only abstract methods (no code) so how can we say that if we are implementing any interface then it is inheritance ? We are not using its code.
>
> Q2. If implementing an interface is not inheritance then How interfaces are used to achieve multiple inheritance ?
>
> Q3. Anyhow what is the benefit of using Interfaces ? They are not having any code. We need to write code again and again in all classes we implement it.

**Then why to make interfaces ?**

**NOTE :** I have found one case in which interfaces are helpful. One example of it is like in Runnable interface we have public void run() method in which we define functionality of thread and there is built in coding that this method will be run as a separate thread. So we just need to code what to do in thread, Rest is pre-defined. But this thing also can be achieved using abstract classes and all.

**Then what are the exact benefits of using interfaces? Is it really Multiple-Inheritance that we achieve using Interfaces?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Interfaces are collection of final static fields and abstract methods (Newly Java 8 added support of having static methods in an interface).

Interfaces are made in situations when we know that some task must be done, but how it should be done can vary. In other words we can say we implement interfaces so that our class starts behaving in a particular way.

Let me explain with an example, we all know what animals are. Like Lion is an animal, monkey is an animal, elephant is an animal, cow is an animal and so on. Now we know all animals do eat something and sleep. But the way each animal can eat something or sleep may differ. Like Lion eats by hunting other animals where as cow eats grass. But both eat. So we can have some pseudo code like this,

```
interface Animal {
    public void eat();
    public void sleep();   
}

class Lion implements Animal {
    public void eat() {
        // Lion's way to eat
    }

    public void sleep(){
         // Lion's way to sleep
    }
}

class Monkey implements Animal {
    public void eat() {
        // Monkey's way to eat
    }

    public void sleep() {
        // Monkey's way to sleep
    }
}
```

As per the pseudo code mentioned above, anything that is capable of eating or sleeping will be called an animal or we can say it is must for all animals to eat and sleep but the way to eat and sleep depends on the animal.

In case of interfaces we inherit only the behaviour, not the actual code as in case of classes' inheritance.

> Q1. As interfaces are having only abstract methods (no code) so how can we say that if we are implementing any interface then it is inheritance ? We are not using its code.

Implementing interfaces is other kind of inheritance. It is not similar to the inheritance of classes as in that inheritance child class gets the real code to reuse from the base class.

> Q2. If implementing an interface is not inheritance then How interfaces are used to achieve multiple inheritance ?

It is said because one class can implement more than one interfaces. But we need to understand that this inheritance is different than classes' inheritance.

> Q3. Anyhow what is the benefit of using Interfaces ? They are not having any code. We need to write code again and again in all classes we implement it.

Implementing an interface puts compulsion on the class that it must override its all abstract methods.

Read more in my book [here](http://www.laxmipublications.com/servlet/lpgetbiblio?bno=B000369&pageName=Keywords) and [here](http://www.amazon.in/Way-Core-Java-Gurparsad-Singh/dp/9386035553/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1466577389&sr=8-1&keywords=the+way+to+core+of+java)

Comment: I feel like the structure that you've build in your code would be better and more logical with extends-inheritance than with implements-interfacing. I think it's a rather bad example

Comment: @gprathour I agree, so please provide a better example :)

Comment: If you want a more practical example of when you'd use an interface and when not. Think of writing an app that has to save some data. In the beginning you know you'll want to save the data, and to load it again, but you might be conflicted as to how: Thus you create an IOInterface. You choose first to write the data to a plain file, and create the FileContext which inherits IOInterface. Then you find out saving it in a SQLite database is actually the thing. THen you can write a SQLiteContext which inherits IOInterface. code was added, not removed, its still compatible. Code by addition.

Comment: A better way would be that animal is the parent class. Monkey and Lion would extend animal. There would be an interface Swing which monkey implements, an interface Roar which Lion would implement.

Comment: @MobDev here the point was to elaborate that two different classes can have their own different implementation for the same interface's methods. It is mandatory for the classes to override the methods, but they can have different code for implementation.

Answer (score 46):

> Q1. As interfaces are having only abstract methods (no code) so how can we say that if we are implementing any interface then it is inheritance ? We are not using its code.

We can't. Interfaces aren't used to achieve multiple inheritance. They replace it with safer, although slightly less powerful construct. Note the keyword `implements` rather than `extends`.

> Q2. If implementing an interface is not inheritance then How interfaces are used to achieve multiple inheritance ?

They are not. With interfaces a single class can have several "*views*", different APIs or capabilities. E.g. A class can be `Runnable` and `Callable` at the same time, while both methods are effectively doing the same thing.

> Q3. Anyhow what is the benefit of using Interfaces ? They are not having any code. We need to write code again and again in all classes we implement it.

Interfaces are kind-of multiple inheritance with no problems that the latter introduces (like the [*Diamond problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem)).

There are few use-cases for interfaces:

1. Object effectively has two identities: a `Tank` *is* both a `Vehicle` and a `Weapon`. You can use an instance of `Tank` where either the former or the latter is expected (polymorphism). This is rarely a case in real-life and is actually a valid example where multiple inheritance would be better (or traits).
2. Simple responsibilities: an instance of `Tank` object in a game is also `Runnable` to let you execute it in a thread and an `ActionListener` to respond to mouse events.
3. Callback interfaces: if object implements given callback interface, it is being notified about its life-cycle or other events.
4. Marker interfaces: not adding any methods, but easily accessible via `instanceof` to discover object capabilities or wishes. `Serializable` and `Cloneable` are examples of this.

What you are looking for are trait (like in Scala), unfortunately unavailable in Java.

Comment: Can you please elaborate benefits of using interfaces ?

Comment: @GPSingh: I tried to add few points below `Q3`. Do you have some further questions?

Comment: The answer to question two - "they are not" used to achieve multiple inheritance, is contradictory to the answer to question three - "interfaces are kind-of multiple inheritance". This makes it somewhat confusing.

Comment: In **Q1:** you said it not used to achieve multiple inheritance but on the **Q2:** If you said kind of multiple inheritance. Could you be more specific and clear?

Answer (score 17):

> Q1. As interfaces are having only abstract methods (no code) so how can we say that if we are implementing any interface then it is inheritance ? We are not using its code.

Unfortunately, in colloquial usage, the word `inheritance` is still frequently used when a class implements an interface, although `interface implementation` would be a preferable term - IMO, the term `inheritance` should strictly be used with inheritance of a concrete or abstract class. In languages like C++ and C#, the same syntax (i.e. `Subclass : Superclass` and `Class : Interface`) is used for both class inheritance and interface implementation, which may have contributed to the spread of the misuse of the word `inheritance` with interfaces. Java has different syntax for `extend`ing a class as opposed to `implement`ing an interface, which is a good thing.

> Q2 If implementing an interface is not inheritance then How interfaces are used to achieve multiple inheritance ?

You can achieve the 'effect' of multiple inheritance through composition - by implementing multiple interfaces on a class, and then providing implementations for all methods, properties and events required of all the interfaces on the class. One common technique of doing this with concrete classes is by doing 'has-a' (composition) relationships with classes which implement the external interfaces by 'wiring up' the implementation to each of the internal class implementations. (Languages such as C++ do support multiple concrete inheritance directly, but which creates other potential issues like the diamond problem).

> Q3 Anyhow what is the benefit of using Interfaces ? They are not having any code. We need to write code again and again in all classes we implement it.

Interfaces allow existing classes (e.g. frameworks) to interact with your new classes without having ever 'seen' them before, because of the ability to communicate through a known interface. Think of an interface as a contract. By implementing this interface on a class, you are contractually bound to meet the obligations required of it, and once this contract is implemented, then your class should be able to be used interchangeably with any other code which consumes the interface.

> Real World Example

A 'real world' example would be the legislation and convention (interface) surrounding an electrical wall socket in a particular country. Each electrical appliance plugged into the socket needs to meet the specifications (contract) that the authorities have defined for the socket, e.g. the positioning of the line, neutral and earth wires, the position and colouring of the on / off switch, and the conformance the  the electrical voltage, frequency and maximum current that will be supplied through the `interface` when it is switched on.

The benefit of decoupling the interface (i.e. a standard wall socket) rather than just soldering wires together is that you can plug (and unplug) a fan, a kettle, a double-adapter, or some new appliance to be invented next year into it, even though this appliance didn't exist when the interface was designed. Why? Because it will *conform* to the requirements of the interface.

> Why use interfaces?

Interfaces are great for loose coupling of classes, and are one of the mainstay's of Uncle Bob's [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) paradigm, especially the `Dependency Inversion Principle` and `Interface Segregation Principles`.

Simply put, by ensuring that dependencies between classes are coupled only on interfaces (abstractions), and not on other concrete classes, it allows the dependency to be substituted with any other class implementation which meets the requirements of the interface.

In testing, stubs and mocks of dependencies can be used to unit test each class, and the interaction the class has with the dependency can be 'spyed' upon.

Comment: You start off by clarifying `interface implementation` vs `concrete inheritance` which is a very important distinction. But your latter use of the term `interface` can be confusing in the real world example. Can something be done to improve clarity? E.g. Real world example of what? Interface, Inheritance? The next phrase could lead one to believe that it is an example of an interface, but the example seems like a concrete implementation.

Comment: Thanks Steve - you're right, my answer was in need of some TLC.

Answer (score 11):

**KISS**

I have searched for days, nay weeks trying to understand interfaces and seem to read the same generic help; I'm not trying to disparage the contributions, but i think the light-bulb just clicked so I'm chuffed :))

I prefer to Keep It Simple Stupid, so will proffer my new found view of interfaces.

I'm a casual coder but i want to post this code i wrote in VB.NET (the principle is the same for other languages), to help others understand interfaces.

If i have it wrong, then please let others know in follow up comments.

**Explanation**

Three buttons on a form, clicking each one saves a different class reference to the interface variable (_data). The whole point of different class references into an interface variable, is what i didn't understand as it seemed redundant, then its power becomes evident with the msgbox, i only need to call the SAME method to perform the task i need, in this case 'GetData()', which uses the method in the class that's currently held by the interface reference variable (_data).

So however i wish to get my data (from a database, the web or a text file), it's only ever done using the **same method name**; the code behind that implementation...i don't care about.

It's then easy to change each class code using the interface without any dependency...this is a key goal in OO and encapsulation.

**When to use**

Code classes and if you notice the same verb used for methods, like 'GetData()', then it's a good candidate to implement an interface on that class and use that method name as an abstraction / interface.

I sincerely hope this helps a fellow noob with this difficult principle.

```
Public Class Form1

Private _data As IData = Nothing

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    _data = New DataText()
    MsgBox(_data.GetData())
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    _data = New DataDB()
    MsgBox(_data.GetData())
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    _data = New DataWeb()
    MsgBox(_data.GetData())
End Sub

End Class

Public Interface IData
Function GetData() As String
End Interface

Friend Class DataText : Implements IData

Friend Function GetData() As String Implements IData.GetData
    Return "DataText"
End Function

End Class

Friend Class DataDB : Implements IData

Friend Function GetData() As String Implements IData.GetData
    Return "DataDB"
End Function

End Class

Friend Class DataWeb : Implements IData

Friend Function GetData() As String Implements IData.GetData
    Return "DataWeb"
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I believe you may mean `instance variable` instead of `interface variable`

Answer (score 10):

Old question. I'm suprised that nobody quoted the canonical sources: *Java: an Overview* by James Gosling, *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software* by the Gang of Four or *Effective Java* by Joshua Bloch (among other sources).

I will start with a quote:

> An interface is simply a specification of a set of methods that an object responds to. It does not include any instance variables or implementation. Interfaces can be multiply-inherited (unlike classes) and they can be used in a more flexible way than the usual rigid class
>   inheritance structure. (Gosling, p.8)

Now, let's take your assumptions and questions one by one (I'll voluntarily ignore the Java 8 features).

## Assumptions

### Interface is collection of ONLY abstract methods and final fields.

Did you see the keyword `abstract` in Java interfaces? No. Then you should not consider an interface as a collection of abstract methods. Maybe you are misleaded by the C++ so-called interfaces, which are classes with only pure virtual methods. C++, by design, does not have (and does not need to have) interfaces, because it has mutliple inheritance.

As explained by Gosling, you should rather consider an interface as "a set of methods that an object responds to". I like to see an interface **and the associated documentation** as a service contract. It describes what you can expect from an object that implements that interface. The documentation should specify the pre and post-conditions (e.g. the parameters should be not null, the output is always positive, ...) and the invariants (a method that does not modify the object internal state). This contract is the heart, I think, of OOP.

### There is no multiple inheritance in Java.

Indeed.

> JAVA omits many rarely used, poorly understood, confusing features of C++ that in our experience bring more grief than benefit. This primarily consists of operator overloading (although it does have method overloading), multiple inheritance, and extensive automatic coercions. (Gosling, p.2)

Nothing to add.

### Interfaces can be used to achieve multiple inheritance in Java.

No, simlpy because there is no multiple inheritance in Java. See above.

### One Strong point of Inheritance is that We can use the code of base class in derived class without writing it again. May be this is the most important thing for inheritance to be there.

That's called "implementation inheritance". As you wrote, it's a convenient way to reuse code.

But it has an important counterpart:

> parent classes often define at least part of their subclasses' physical representation. Because inheritance exposes a subclass to details of its parent's implementation, it's often said that "inheritance breaks encapsulation" [Sny86]. The implementation of a subclass becomes so bound up with the implementation of its parent class that any change in the parent's implementation will force the subclass to change. (GOF, 1.6)

(There is a similar quote in Bloch, item 16.)

Actually, inheritance serves also another purpose:

> Class inheritance combines interface inheritance and implementation inheritance. Interface inheritance defines a new interface in terms of one
>   or more existing interfaces. Implementation inheritance defines a new implementation in terms of one or more existing implementations. (GOF, Appendix A)

Both use the keyword `extends` in Java. You may have hierarchies of classes and hierarchies of interfaces. The first ones share implementation, the second ones share obligation.

## Questions

### Q1. As interfaces are having only abstract methods (no code) so how can we say that if we are implementing any interface then it is inheritance ? We are not using its code.**

Implementation of an interface is not inheritance. It's implementation. Thus the keyword `implements`.

### Q2. If implementing an interface is not inheritance then How interfaces are used to achieve multiple inheritance ?**

No multiple inheritance in Java. See above.

### Q3. Anyhow what is the benefit of using Interfaces ? They are not having any code. We need to write code again and again in all classes we implement it./Then why to make interfaces ?/What are the exact benefits of using interfaces? Is it really Multiple-Inheritance that we achieve using Interfaces?

The most important question is: **why would you like to have multiple-inheritance?** I can think of two answers: 1. to give mutliple types to an object; 2. to reuse code.

#### Give mutliple types to an object

In OOP, one object may have *different types*. For instance in Java, an `ArrayList<E>` has the following types: `Serializable`, `Cloneable`, `Iterable<E>`, `Collection<E>`, `List<E>`, `RandomAccess`, `AbstractList<E>`, `AbstractCollection<E>` and `Object` (I hope I have not forgotten anyone). If an object has different types, various consumers will be able use it without be aware of its specificities. I need an `Iterable<E>` and you give me a `ArrayList<E>`? It's ok. But if I need now a `List<E>` and you give me a `ArrayList<E>`, it's ok too. Etc.

How do you type an object in OOP? You took the `Runnable` interface as an example, and this example is perfect to illustrate the answer to this question. I quote the official Java doc:

> In addition, Runnable provides the means for a class to be active while not subclassing Thread.

Here's the point: **Inheritance is a convenient way of *typing* objects.** You want to create a thread? Let's subclass the `Thread` class. You want an object to have different types, let's use mutliple-inheritance. Argh. It doesn't exist in Java. (In C++, if you want an object to have different types, multiple-inheritance is the way to go.)

How to give mutliple types to an object then? In Java, you can type your object *directly*. That's what you do when your class `implements` the `Runnable` interface. Why use `Runnable` if your a fan of inheritance? Maybe because your class is already a subclass of another class, let's say `A`. Now your class has two types: `A` and `Runnable`.

With multiple interfaces, you can give multiple types to an object. You just have to create a class that `implements` multiple interfaces. As long as you are compliant with the contracts, it's ok.

#### Reuse code

This is a difficult subject; I've already quoted the GOF on breaking the encapsulation. Other answer mentionned the diamond problem. You could also think of the Single Responsibility Principle:

> A class should have only one reason to change. (Robert C. Martin,  Agile Software Development, Principles, Patterns, and Practices)

Having a parent class may give a class a reason to change, besides its own responsibilities:

> The superclass’s implementation may change from release to  release,  and  if  it  does,  the  subclass  may  break,  even  though  its  code  has  not been touched. As a consequence, a subclass must evolve in tandem with its superclass (Bloch, item 16).

I would add a more prosaic issue: I always have a weird feeling when I try to find the source code of a method in a class and I can't find it. Then I remember: it must be defined somewhere in the parent class. Or in the grandparent class. Or maybe even higher. A good IDE is a valuable asset in this case, but it remains, in my mind, something magical. Nothing similar with hierarchies of interfaces, since the javadoc is the only thing I need: one keyboard shortcut in the IDE and I get it.

Inheritance howewer has advantages:

> It is safe to use inheritance within a package, where the subclass and the superclass implementations are under the control of the same programmers. It is also safe to use inheritance when extending classes specifically designed and documented for extension (Item  17: Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it).  (Bloch, item 16)

An example of a class "specifically designed and documented for extension" in Java is `AbstractList`.

But Bloch and GOF insist on this: "Favor composition over inheritance":

> Delegation is a way of making composition as powerful for reuse as inheritance [Lie86, JZ91]. In delegation, two objects are involved in handling a request: a receiving object delegates operations to its delegate. This is analogous to subclasses deferring requests to parent classes. (GOF p.32)

**If you use composition, you won't have to write the same code again and again.** You just create a class that handles the duplications, and you pass an instance of this class to the classes that implements the interface. It's a very simple way to reuse code. And this helps you to follow the Single Responsibility Principle and make the code more testable.  Rust and Go don't have inheritance (they don't have classes either), but I don't think that the code is more redundant than in other OOP languages.

Furthermore, if you use composition, you will find yourself naturally using interfaces to give your code the structure and the flexibility it needs (see other answers on use cases of interfaces).

*Note: you can share code with Java 8 interfaces*

And finally, one last quote:

> During the memorable Q&A session, someone asked him [James Gosling]: "If you could do Java over again, what would you change?" "I'd leave out classes" (anywhere on the net, don't know if this is true)

Answer (score 5):

*This is very old question and java-8 release have added more features & power to interface.*

An interface declaration can contain

1. method signatures
2. default methods
3. static methods
4. constant definitions.

*The only methods that have implementations in interface are **default** and **static** methods.*

**Uses of interface:**

1. To define a **contract**
2. To link unrelated classes with has a **capabilities** (e.g. classes implementing Serializable interface may or may not have any relation between them except implementing that interface
3. To provide **interchangeable** implementation e.g. [`Strategy_pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)
4. **default** methods enable you to add new functionality to the interfaces of your libraries and ensure *binary compatibility* with code written for older versions of those interfaces
5. Organize helper methods in your libraries with **static** methods ( you can keep static methods specific to an interface in the same interface rather than in a separate class)

Have a look at this related SE question for code example to understanding the concepts better:

[How should I have explained the difference between an Interface and an Abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777989/how-should-i-have-explained-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-an-abstract/34978606#34978606)

Coming back to your queries:

*Q1. As interfaces are having only abstract methods (no code) so how can we say that if we are implementing any interface then it is inheritance ? We are not using its code.*

*Q2. If implementing an interface is not inheritance then How interfaces are used to achieve multiple inheritance ?*

Interface can contain code for **static** and **default** methods. These default methods provides backward compatibility & static methods provides *helper/utility* functions.

You can't have true multiple inheritance in java and interface is not the way to get it. Interface can contain only constants. So you can't inherit state but you can implement behaviour.

You can replace *inheritance* with *capability*. *Interface provides multiple capabilities to implementing classes.*

*Q3. Anyhow what is the benefit of using Interfaces ? They are not having any code. We need to write code again and again in all classes we implement it.*

Refer to "**uses of interface**" section in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Inheritance is when one class derives from another class (which can be abstract) or an Interface. The strongest point of object oriented (inheritance) is not reuse of code (there are many ways to do it), but polymorphism.

Polymorphism is when you have code that uses the interface, which it's instance object can be of any class derived from that interface. For example I can have such a method:
public void Pet(IAnimal animal) and this method will get an object which is an instance of Dog or Cat which inherit from IAnimal. or I can have such a code: 
IAnimal animal
and then I can call a method of this interface:
animal.Eat() which Dog or Cat can implement in a different way.

The main advantage of interfaces is that you can inherit from some of them, but if you need to inherit from only one you can use an abstract class as well. Here is an article which explains more about the differences between an abstract class and an interface:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/abstractsvsinterfaces.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Both Methods Work (Interfaces and Multiple Inheritance).

**Quick Practical Short Answer**

Interfaces are better when you have several years of experience using Multiple Inheritance that have Super Classes with only method definition, and no code at all.

A complementary question may be: "How and Why to to migrate code from Abstract Classes to Interfaces".

If you are not using many abstract classes, in your application, or you don't have many experience with it, you may prefer to skip interfaces.

Dont rush to use interfaces.

**Long Boring Answer**

Interfaces are very similar, or even equivalent to abstract Classes.

If your code has many Abstract classes, then its time you start thinking in terms of Interfaces.

The following code with abstract classes:

---

### MyStreamsClasses.java

```
/* File name : MyStreamsClasses.java */
import java.lang.*;
// Any number of import statements

public abstract class InputStream {
  public void ReadObject(Object MyObject);
}

public abstract class OutputStream {
  public void WriteObject(Object MyObject);
}

public abstract class InputOutputStream 
    imnplements InputStream, OutputStream {
  public void DoSomethingElse();
}
```

---

Can be replaced with:

---

### MyStreamsInterfaces.java

```
/* File name : MyStreamsInterfaces.java */
import java.lang.*;
// Any number of import statements

public interface InputStream {
  public void ReadObject(Object MyObject);
}

public interface OutputStream {
  public void WriteObject(Object MyObject);
}

public interface InputOutputStream 
    extends InputStream, OutputStream {
  public void DoSomethingElse();
}
```

---

Cheers.

Comment: can you please explain why we need to convert abstract class to interfaces? like as mentioned why we need to convert the abstract classes to interfaces?

Comment: @Muhammad_08 : interfaces is a more defined way to express an abstraction / idea than abstract classes, altought both ways work.

Comment: thank you for the response, what i can deduce from your answer that is its more closer to professionalism and software eng rules to use interfaces instead of abstract classes?

Comment: @Muhammad_08 Is more related to have a easier direct syntax that allows programmers to express an idea, even if there are other ways

Answer (score 1):

So. There are a lot of excellent answers here explaining in detail what an interface is. Yet, this is an example of its use, in the way one of my best colleagues ever explained it to me years ago, with what I have learned at university in the last couple of years mixed in.

An interface is a kind of 'contract'. It exposes some methods, fields and so on, that are available. It does not reveal any of its implementation details, only what it returns, and which parameters it takes. And in here lies the answer to question three, and what I feel is one of the greatest strengths of modern OOP:

> *"Code by addition, Not by modification"* - Magnus Madsen, AAU

That's what he called it at least, and he may have it from some other place. The sample code below is written in C#, but everything shown can be done just about the same way in Java.

What we see is a class called SampleApp, that has a single field, the IOContext. IOContext is an interface.
SampleApp does not care one wit about how it saves its data, it just needs to do so, in its "doSomething()" method.

We can imagine that saving the data may have been more important than HOW it was saved at the beginning of the development process, so the developer chose to simply write the FileContext class. Later on, however, he needed to support JSON for whatever reason. So he wrote the JSONFileContext class, which inherits FileContext. This means that it is effectively an IOContext, which has the functionality of FileContext, save the replacement of FileContexts SaveData and LoadData, it still uses its 'write/read' methods.

Implementing the JSON class has been a small amount of work, comparing to writing the class, and having it just inherit IOContext.

The field of SampleApp could have been just of type 'FileContext', but that way, it would have been restricted to ever only using children of that class. By making the interface, we can even do the SQLiteContext implementation, and write to a database, SampleApp will never know or care, and when we have written the SQL lite class, we need only make one change to our code: `new JSONFileContext();` instead becomes `new SQLiteContext();`

We still have our old implementations and can switch back to those if the need arises. We have broken nothing, and all the changes to our code are half a line, that can be changed back within the blink of an eye.

so: Code by addition, NOT by modification.

```
namespace Sample
{
    class SampleApp
    {
        private IOContext context;

        public SampleApp()
        {
            this.context = new JSONFileContext(); //or any of the other implementations
        }

        public void doSomething()
        {
            //This app can now use the context, completely agnostic of the actual implementation details.
            object data = context.LoadData();
            //manipulate data
            context.SaveData(data);
        }
    }

    interface IOContext
    {
        void SaveData(object data);
        object LoadData();
    }

    class FileContext : IOContext
    {
        public object LoadData()
        {

            object data = null;
            var fileContents = loadFileContents();
            //Logic to turn fileContents into a data object
            return data;
        }

        public void SaveData(object data)
        {
            //logic to create filecontents from 'data'
            writeFileContents(string.Empty);
        }

        protected void writeFileContents(string fileContents)
        {
            //writes the fileContents to disk
        }

        protected string loadFileContents()
        {
            string fileContents = string.Empty;
            //loads the fileContents and returns it as a string
            return fileContents;
        }
    }

    class JSONFileContext : FileContext
    {
        public new void SaveData(object data)
        {
            //logic to create filecontents from 'data'
            base.writeFileContents(string.Empty);
        }

        public new object LoadData()
        {
            object data = null;
            var fileContents = loadFileContents();
            //Logic to turn fileContents into a data object
            return data;
        }
    }

    class SQLiteContext : IOContext
    {
        public object LoadData()
        {
            object data = null;
            //logic to read data into the data object
            return data;
        }

        public void SaveData(object data)
        {
            //logic to save the data object in the database
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Interfaces

An interface is a contract defining how to interact with an object. They are useful to express how your internals intend to interact with an object. Following **Dependency Inversion** your public API would have all parameters expressed with interfaces. You don't care how it does what you need it to do, just that it does exactly what you need it to do.

**Example:** You may simply need a `Vehicle` to transport goods, you don't care about the particular mode of transport.

## Inheritance

Inheritance is an extension of a particular implementation. That implementation may or may not satisfy a particular interface. You should expect an ancestor of a particular implementation only when you care about the how.

**Example:** You may need a `Plane` implementation of a vehicle for fast transport.

## Composition

Composition can be used as an alternative to inheritance. Instead of your class extending a base class, it is created with objects that implement smaller portions of the main class's responsibility. Composition is used in the `facade pattern` and `decorator pattern`.

**Example:** You may create a `DuckBoat` ([DUKW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUKW)) class that implements `LandVehicle` and `WaterVehicle` which both implement `Vehicle` composed of `Truck` and `Boat` implementations.

## Answers

> Q1. As interfaces are having only abstract methods (no code) so how can we say that if we are implementing any interface then it is inheritance ? We are not using its code.

Interfaces are not inheritance. Implementing an interface expresses that you intend for your class to operate in the way that is defined by the interface. Inheritance is when you have a common ancestor, and you receive the same behavior (`inherit`) as the ancestor so you do not need to define it.

> Q2. If implementing an interface is not inheritance then How interfaces are used to achieve multiple inheritance ?

Interfaces do not achieve multiple inheritance. They express that a class may be suitable for multiple roles.

> Q3. Anyhow what is the benefit of using Interfaces ? They are not having any code. We need to write code again and again in all classes we implement it.

One of the major benefits of interfaces is to provide separation of concerns:

- You can write a class that does something with another class without caring how that class is implemented.
- Any future development can be compatible with your implementation without needing to extend a particular base class.

In the spirit of `DRY` you can write an implementation that satisfies an interface and change it while still respecting the `open/closed principal` if you leverage composition.

Comment: Would help if you can go more on the how rather than `Interfaces are not inheritance.`, this way it helps break down the definition where me as a noob is still having trouble to see the different and similar. anywho, thanks you for explanation.

Comment: @Kim.LBy Thanks for the input. Does that clarify better?

Comment: yes, it's clearer now. The edited answer shows which values the concrete classes inherit from their parents' classes and not from the interface.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1. As interfaces are having only abstract methods (no code) so how can we say that if we are implementing an interface then it is inheritance? We are not using its code.**

It is not equal inheritance. It is just similiar. Let me explain:

```
VolvoV3 extends VolvoV2, and VolvoV2 extends    Volvo (Class)
VolvoV3 extends VolvoV2, and VolvoV2 implements Volvo (Interface)

line1: Volvo v = new VolvoV2(); 
line2: Volvo v = new VolvoV3();
```

If you see only line1 and line2 you can infer that VolvoV2 and VolvoV3 have the same type. You cannot infer if Volvo a superclass or Volvo is an interface.

**Q2. If implementing an interface is not inheritance then How interfaces are used to achieve multiple inheritances?**

Now using interfaces:

```
VolvoXC90 implements XCModel and Volvo (Interface)
VolvoXC95 implements XCModel and Volvo (Interface)

line1: Volvo   a = new VolvoXC90();
line2: Volvo   a = new VolvoXC95();
line3: XCModel a = new VolvoXC95();
```

If you see only line1 and line2 you can infer that VolvoXC90 and VolvoXC95 have the same type (Volvo). You cannot infer that Volvo is a superclass or Volvo is an interface.

If you see only line2 and line3 you can infer that Volvo95 implements two types, XCModel and Volvo, in Java you know that at least one has to be an interface. If this code was written in C++, for instance, they could be both classes. Therefore, multiple inheritances.

**Q3. Anyhow, what is the benefit of using Interfaces? They are not having any code. We need to write code again and again in all classes we implement it.**

Imagine a system where you use a VolvoXC90 class in 200 other classes.

```
VolvoXC90 v = new VolvoXC90();
```

If you need to evolve your system to launch VolvoXC95 you have to alter 200 other classes.

Now, imagine a system where you use a Volvo interface in 10,000,000 classes.

```
// Create VolvoXC90 but now we need to create VolvoXC95
Volvo v = new VolvoFactory().newCurrentVolvoModel();
```

Now, if you need to evolve your system to create VolvoXC95 models you have to alter only one class, the Factory.

It is a common sense question. If your system is composed only of few classes and have few updates use Interfaces everywhere is counterproductive. For big systems, it can save you a lot of pain and avoid risk adopting Interfaces.

I recommend you read more about S.O.L.I.D principles and read the book Effective Java. It has good lessons from experienced software engineers.