# Logic behind using Interfaces in OOPS ? Java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why to use Interfaces ? Multiple Inheritance vs Interfaces ? Benefits of Interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531292/why-to-use-interfaces-multiple-inheritance-vs-interfaces-benefits-of-interfa)

I want to know why do we use ***interfaces*** as they contain only *declaration* of methods. Not any code...

Then, what are the **benefits** of using interfaces? Why to implement them? Why to use them?

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8531292/1055241 look at the accepted answer to get idea of using interfaces

Comment: Even if the downvotes are just for the duplicate question, the referred to question - just judging from it's title - might not have been obvious to the OP (him looking for the logic/meaning of interfaces). Anyways, while this is a newbie question, there seems to be nothing wrong with it, other than something similar having been asked before. So could all those downvoters please add a helpful comment, on why this question is unclear or not useful? Thx.

Comment: Interfaces are not meant to actually do something, they are rather used to describe and guarantee what an implementing class is capable of doing! For example an interface named `IEatable` could have a method `eat()`, which concrete classes like `Cookie`, `Hamburger`, or `Spinach` could implement. You can therefore be sure that those classes will each have a method `eat()`. But calling it for `Cookie` might print "Yum yum!", whilst `Spinach` just outputs "Yuk!".

Answer (score 1):

You already mentioned the point: Because you then code against objects that implement those interfaces, instead of the concrete object-class.
Advantage: Your code will work with any implementation that implements this interface.

You are basically hiding implementation, saying: "I dont care about the concrete implementation, as long as the object is offering this interface"..