# what is abstract interface according to the definition in java docs?

Tags: java

as i know interface is fully abstract class whose methods are public by default and data members are public static final.
so, what is abstract interface?

```
public abstract interface Servlet {
public abstract void init(ServletConfig paramServletConfig)
        throws ServletException;

public abstract ServletConfig getServletConfig();

public abstract void service(ServletRequest paramServletRequest,
        ServletResponse paramServletResponse) throws ServletException,
        IOException;

public abstract String getServletInfo();

public abstract void destroy();
```

}

Comment: Useful link for interfaces http://stackoverflow.com/q/8531292/1055241

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces and their methods are abstract by default. Adding abstract doesn't mean anything different

```
public abstract interface example {
}
```

is same as

```
public interface example {
}
```

Although older versions of java required an interface to have the keyword 'abstract'. It is obsolete now and should not be used

Comment: WITH THE RELEASE OF JAVA 8 WE CAN HAVE NOW DEFAULT AND STATIC IMPLEMENTED METHODS TOO INSIDE INTERFACE AND THEY ARE NOT ABSTRACT BY DEFAULT.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are abstract by default appending `abstract` keyword to interface & its method signature is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is encapsulation of `final fields + abstract methods`.

An abstract class may have `final fields + variables + concrete methods + abstract methods`

So when we are declaring abstract methods in abstract classes then we do need to write `abstract` keyword and if we want to declare a class to be abstract then we need to add `abstract` keyword to it.

But in case of interface they will only be having abstract methods. So writing `abstract` keyword with interface or its methods is not compulsory. They will be by default abstract.

**New in Java8**

[Interfaces can have default methods too](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)