# Method name overloading and self reference parameter

Tags: java, this, overloading, strategy-pattern, self-reference

I have some client classes `A`, `B` and `C` that need to use an operation `op()` that depends on the type of the caller and it's defined by another class `D`.

There are a few solutions:

1. `D` exposes a different method for each client but the responsibility of choosing the right implementation is left to the client:
   [image: UML]
2. overloading the method name in `D` and passing the client self-reference to drive the binding:
   [image: UML]
3. introducing a strategy pattern.
4. ...

Is there some good practice why I should avoid the second solution?

Comment: *"Is there some good practice why I should avoid the second solution?"* Why do you think you should avoid it?

Comment: @Tom I don't know. That's why I'm asking...

Comment: I'd like to see some code here.  Is there a reason that `op()` in in a separate class and not just a member of the three previous classes?

Comment: [Exact need of Method Overloading in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38967498)

Comment: @markspace There's no code. It's just an hypothetical situation that I've created because I'm studying for the SW engineering exam.

Comment: @Tom in the question you linked I can't find if there's a reason to avoid passing the self reference in cases like the one I've described, even so I agree and understand what are the benefits of using the overloading